# I want to execute code when every action is called in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

I'm new to MVC3, and my site has a setting that if the site is open. So, I need to check this value when every action is called.

The idea is like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if(!settings.SiteIsOpen)
    {
        // redirect to siteclosed page
    }
    // someaction logic...
}
```

I know that there are something called Filter in MVC3, and need to register it RegisterGlobalFilters. I want to use this feature, but I don't know the detail steps to implement that.

Can anyone help me? thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can start on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute). It should get you started on where you want to go. You'll just need to figure out where in the request you want to apply your action.

Answer (score 2):

You probably had to create a custom action filter and decorate your Action result like this

```
     [CustomActionFilter]
     public ActionResult SomeAction()
     {
     }
```

Inside CustomActionFilter you have to implement abstract class ActionFilterAttribute

```
    public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
        // your logic here
       }
    }
```

The ASP.NET MVC framework will call the OnActionExecuting method of your action filter before it calls any action method that is marked with your action filter attribute.

For more details go through this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx